# emulating LiveHTTPheaders server side

Tags: php, linux

Is it possible to 'translate' headers from this firefox extension into server side script?

edit:

I'm trying to **SEND** headers, not retrieve them. I performed some actions in browser and i want them to be automatically repeated (with few changes) by server-side script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP's [`header()`](http://php.net/header) function to send headers to the user's browser.

If you're making HTTP requests to other sites from your server, use [cURL](http://php.net/curl)'s [`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/curl_setopt) function to set the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option - you can provide an array of headers to pass along with your request.

Comment: i'm thinking about posting for example

Comment: ...so i want to send headers from my site to other sites and/or to other pages on my site

Comment: OK, I've updated with information on doing it from your site to another page.

Comment: stuff like with curl - posting to forms, etc but without coding whole curl session... just taking headers (for example when i posted to form on my site via browser) from firefox extension and repeating them

Answer (score 0):

Consider `print_r(apache_request_headers());`

[PHP Manual: apache_request_headers()](http://www.php.net/apache_request_headers)

Here is an [example](http://web.midg3t.net/test/headers.php) and its [source code](http://web.midg3t.net/test/headers.phps).

Comment: that's pretty cool, but i DO have headers... i want to post them, not retrieve them

Answer (score 0):

Use the [cURL functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) for your request and use [curl_setopt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

```
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  array('Referer: http://www.example.com/'));
```